# AMPScript SubString Adding in Additional Character

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, substring

I am trying to work out a way to personalize emails whereby I utilize the "Full Name" field but parse the data after the first space. I am having issues with my AMPScript for this block:

```
%%[
  SET @FullName = [First Name]
  SET @WhiteSpacePos = IndexOf(@FullName, ' ')
  SET @FirstNamePos = Add(@WhiteSpacePos, 1)
  SET @FirstName = Substring(@FullName, 1, @FirstNamePos)
]%%
```

After doing this, it brings up the values; however, it's 90% perfect. The issue is that the first initial of the second name comes up, e.g., "Sam Smith" comes out "Sam S"

The other issue is that in places where there is just one name. In this case, for example, "Sam" comes out simply just "S".

Any ideas on how to work around these?

Thanks,

Shmuel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

substring takes a length argument as the third option, and using the index value from the space gives 1 more length than the first name.  Either skip adding 1 to the @WhiteSpacePos value, or use @WhiteSpacePos-1 as the length to substring.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for writing in. I'm not following you regarding skip adding 1 to the `@WhiteSpacePos`  value. Do you mean to set this line to:

  `SET @FirstNamePos = Add(@WhiteSpacePos, 0)`

or
  `SET @FirstNamePos = Add(@WhiteSpacePos)`

Either way, both methods didn't work for me and brought up an error.

Regarding `@WhiteSpacePos-1` do you mean adding in a 5th line into the script?

Thanks,

Shmuel

Comment: I mean you can take out the ADD line entirely, it should not be necessary.  Try this:
%%[
  SET @FullName = [First Name]
  SET @WhiteSpacePos = IndexOf(@FullName, ' ')
  SET @FirstName = Substring(@FullName, 1, @FirstNamePos)
]%%
`
Although that may still catch the whitespace character.  If so, put the add part back in, and add -1

Comment: Thanks Mark! It kind of worked and you gave me the idea to run a VAR AMPScript that uses the `INDEXOF` query to see if there's a space in the name field. If so, then I used the "fancy" code to parse out only the first name; if not, then I just use the simplified code to use the name.